# VectorTile Layer not updating

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am having a strange issue when using `ol.layer.VectorTile` layer using openlayers 4.2.0.

For the `ol.source.VectorTile` I am using a `tileLoadFunction` to make network requests for the tiles in my tileGrid. I have about 100 points on my map in the layer. There are certain options a user can choose, which will go to a function where the `VectorTile` layer and `VectorTile` source are redefined, and the layer is removed and read, so that new points are drawn on the map.

Things seem to be fine after switching the layer a few times, but eventually, the `tileLoadFunction` stops getting called. Sometimes it will get called like 3 times or something but then stops getting called, even though there are many more tiles in the `tileGrid`. I am not sure what is happening, like it is reaching some kind of limit or something that is preventing it from calling the `tileLoadFunction`? I have tried to use the `.refresh()` on the source in case this is the problem, but that did nothing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a check for whether there were any features in the data for a given tile, and if not I skipped the `tile.setFeatures()` function for that tile.  This messed something up in the scheme of things.

The solution was to not check for data, and just `setFeatures` with an empty `featureCollection` if the data did not have any features for a particular tile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and setting `tile.setFeatures([]);` solved it!